match two or more of the preceding token and replace
I am looking to replace his/her based on gender, but i have to make sure that if it's comes between the line then must be starting small his/her or starting of line or after statement end it must be starting capital His/Her.
Eg.: ###HIS_HER### Ability is good. Test ###HIS_HER### Ability is good.###HIS_HER### Test Done.
Output Expected : His Ability is good. Test his Ability is good.His Test Done.
var text = "###HIS_HER### Ability is good. Test ###HIS_HER### Ability is good.###HIS_HER### Test Done.";
var replace = "his";

var Replace = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[A-Z][a-z]\s*"+search);
text = Replace .Replace(text,replace);
return text;


There is no option to capitalize conditionally the result in .NET regex engine, as fare as I know. One approach would be to use 2 different tags ###HIS_HER_UPP### and ###HIS_HER_LOW### for instance.

Sentence capitalization isn't a job for regular expressions. Use regex to replace the tags and then a library like Humanizer to capitalize the result.

@PanagiotisKanavos as good as Humanizer is, it does not handle division into sentences when converting to sentence case (because this is not a simple problem): https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/main/src/Humanizer/Transformer/ToSentenceCase.cs

See this C# demo. Won't work with abbreviations.

With Regex.Replace you do not need to match the whole input, just the part you need to replace. And the part to replace is clearly deiminated, so start by ignoring the capitalisation requirement and this is as simple as:
// at class scope
[GeneratedRegex("###HIS_HER###")]
private static partial Regex PronounTokenRegex();

// in method
var result = PronounTokenRegex().Replace(input, GetPronoun());

But note this really does not need a regex, there is nothing in the search pattern that is a regex meta-char:
var result = input.Replace("###HIS_HER###", GetPronoun());

Thus the simple case is t trivial. But working out, in English, when you are at the start of a sentence is, in general, very hard. The first sentence in a paragraph has nothing before it to check, a period could be due to an abbreviation, and numbered lists are just three cases. (Use a tool that automatically capitalises the start of sentences for a while and see how often it is wrong!)
In your example input:
###HIS_HER### Ability is good. Test ###HIS_HER### Ability is good.###HIS_HER### Test Done

you have multiple cases that look wrong (why is "Ability" in the middle of a sentence capitalised unless you are going for title case, in which case yet different rules apply).
This is why established publications have style rules that define the detail of these cases (for example how are articles capitalised in titles).
There are two options, one: invest hugely and still have errors; two: use different tokens for capitalised.
I would suggest the latter as it is much simpler. And look at Humanizer to do the capitalisation.
var result = input.Replace("###his_her###", GetPronoun())
                  .Replace("###HIS_HER###", GetPropnon().Transform(To.TitleCase)

